# add an object of a class into arraylist and then retrieve it's data member using arraylist

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, arraylist, c#-3.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace classQuiz
{
class A {
    public int a = 100;
    public int b = 200;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A obj = new A();//object of that class
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.Add(obj);//passing object
        Console.WriteLine(list[0]);//output down the code
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
 }
}
```

Output:-

```
         classQuiz.A
```

In this program i am passing object to array list what i want is how can i write its data members on console using array list.I want to access them using array list.I have tried

```
list[0].a;
//or
list[0].b;
```

What can be done to acheive this?

```
        +
```

i do not want to change arraylist to List
I m really very confused. :D

Comment: Don´t use `ArrayList` anymore, use `List<T>` instead as `ArrayList` contains only instances of type `object` which don´t have an `a` or `b` member.

Comment: Why don´t you want to change to List<T>? Without any strong reason it´s hard for us to help you to make your code better and easier to maintain.

Comment: Ok  i was looking for the second way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem occurs as an `ArrayList` is just a collection of `objet`-instances which don´t have any knowledge on your actual types. So you have towo possibilites:

1. cast every item to its actual type:

   ```
   A obj = new A();//object of that class
   ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
   list.Add(obj);//passing object
   ((A)list[0]).a = 1;            // list[0] is just object
   ```
2. or the better approach: use a generic collection, such as `List<T>` which is strongly-typed:

   ```
   A obj = new A();//object of that class
   List<A>list = new List<A>();
   list.Add(obj);//passing object // list[0] is of your actual type
   obj.a = 1;
   ```

Comment: well that's i want

Answer (score 2):

This is because `ArrayList` doesn't know what kind of object that it is storing. It only knows that stores `Object`s, that's all. Because of this, the compiler is not sure about whether there is a memeber called `a` or `b`.

You should use `List<A>` instead, which *does* know the type of object it stores. Just change this:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

to this:

```
List<A> list = new List<A>();
```

Also add a `using` directive:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Then, `Console.WriteLine(list[0].a);` and `Console.WriteLine(list[0].b);` shoud work.

If you can only use `ArrayList`, cast the object in the list to `A`:

```
Console.WriteLine(((A)list[0]).a);
Console.WriteLine(((A)list[0]).b);
```

Comment: i do not want to change arraylist to List<A>

Comment: I have already provided a solution that does not use `List<A>`! Did you not notice? @AwaisAhmad

Comment: i tried but i cannot understand but now i got it :D